# Why can't I change the priority of my Firebase reference (Permission denied)

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In my [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), I have an object that looks like this:

```
person
---- name
---- age
```

When I try to create it for the first time, I use this command:

```
firebaseRef.child("person").setValue(...)
```

That works fine.

Sometimes I want to create this entry with a priority, and this can be done like this:

```
firebaseRef.child("person").setValue(..., myPriority)
```

This works fine as well.

However, the priority should be updated later. I tried the following:

```
firebaseRef.child("person").setPriority(myPriority)
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the error message "Permission denied". Why is this?

The security rules for that reference are as follows:

```
"person": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "name": { ".validate": "newData.isString()" }
    "age": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" }
    "$other": { ".validate": false }
}
```

As can be seen, the node is both readable and writeable.

Comment: this behaviour has been fixed and will be in production by the end of next week.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem:**

The reason for the "Permission denied" error is obviously in the security rules.

The problem is that the priority is stored in the "hidden" property `.priority` which is rarely mentioned in the documentation.

That property is not shown in the Firebase Forge (dashboard) but can be seen when exporting the raw JSON.

Now the directive `"$other": { ".validate": false }` prevents any property other than `name` and `age` from being validated. Thus the error "Permission denied" is raised.

I don't know, however, why the object can be written in the first place when using `setValue(..., myPriority)`. This should cause an error as well.

**The (half-way) solution:**

Now it seems obvious to add a new directive to the security rules that looks like this:

```
".priority": { ".validate": true }
```

But this doesn't work. Firebase Forge responds with:

```
Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")
```

This means that we cannot properly solve this issue. We have to adjust our existing security rules with some drawback: The rule `"$other": { ".validate": false }` has to be removed when we want to update priorities, leaving us with an imperfect validation.

Comment: In addition to this answer, one work-around for now is `"$other":{".validate":"$other.beginsWith('.')"}` - we're working hard on some fixes that make this whole area far more intuitive

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your tip. Are there any news about this?